# How to substitute None values in python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to work with a dataset that has `None` values:

My uploading code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests
url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/statlog/heart/heart.dat"
s = requests.get(url).content
s = s.decode('utf-8')
s_rows = s.split('\n')
s_rows_cols = [each.split() for each in s_rows]
header_row = ['age','sex','chestpain','restBP','chol','sugar','ecg','maxhr','angina','dep','exercise','fluor','thal','diagnosis']
c = pd.DataFrame(s_rows_cols, columns = header_row)
```

and
the output from `c` is :
[image]

But it seems that there are some columns that has `None` values.
How do I replace this `None` values by zeros?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not necessary, if use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) with `sep=\s+` for whitespace separator and also parameter `names` for specify new columns names:

```
url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/statlog/heart/heart.dat"

cols = ['age','sex','chestpain','restBP','chol','sugar','ecg',
        'maxhr','angina','dep','exercise','fluor','thal','diagnosis']
df = pd.read_csv(url, sep='\s+', names=cols)
```

---

```
print (df)
      age  sex  chestpain  restBP   chol  sugar  ecg  maxhr  angina  dep  \
0    70.0  1.0        4.0   130.0  322.0    0.0  2.0  109.0     0.0  2.4   
1    67.0  0.0        3.0   115.0  564.0    0.0  2.0  160.0     0.0  1.6   
2    57.0  1.0        2.0   124.0  261.0    0.0  0.0  141.0     0.0  0.3   
3    64.0  1.0        4.0   128.0  263.0    0.0  0.0  105.0     1.0  0.2   
4    74.0  0.0        2.0   120.0  269.0    0.0  2.0  121.0     1.0  0.2   
..    ...  ...        ...     ...    ...    ...  ...    ...     ...  ...   
265  52.0  1.0        3.0   172.0  199.0    1.0  0.0  162.0     0.0  0.5   
266  44.0  1.0        2.0   120.0  263.0    0.0  0.0  173.0     0.0  0.0   
267  56.0  0.0        2.0   140.0  294.0    0.0  2.0  153.0     0.0  1.3   
268  57.0  1.0        4.0   140.0  192.0    0.0  0.0  148.0     0.0  0.4   
269  67.0  1.0        4.0   160.0  286.0    0.0  2.0  108.0     1.0  1.5   

     exercise  fluor  thal  diagnosis  
0         2.0    3.0   3.0          2  
1         2.0    0.0   7.0          1  
2         1.0    0.0   7.0          2  
3         2.0    1.0   7.0          1  
4         1.0    1.0   3.0          1  
..        ...    ...   ...        ...  
265       1.0    0.0   7.0          1  
266       1.0    0.0   7.0          1  
267       2.0    0.0   3.0          1  
268       2.0    0.0   6.0          1  
269       2.0    3.0   3.0          2  

[270 rows x 14 columns]
```

Then in data are not `None`s and no missing values:

```
print (df.isna().any(1).any())
False
```

EDIT:

If need replace missing values or `None`s to scalar use `fillna`:

```
c = c.fillna(0)
```